# JSF 1.2 startElement and writeAttribute explanation

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-1.2

I've had occasion to write some custom renderers for my project and that's working perfectly well. However I am somewhat confused by some of the parameters in the ResponseWriter methods. The documentation doesn't explain this very well so I'm hoping one of the resident JSF experts can explain this better. Specifically:

```
public abstract void startElement(java.lang.String name,
                              javax.faces.component.UIComponent component)
                       throws java.io.IOException

Parameters:
    name - Name of the element to be started
    component - The UIComponent (if any) to which this element corresponds
```

What does that second parameter actually do? It seems to work fine whether i pass "null" or "this" in my renderer?

Similarly for writeAttribute:

```
public abstract void writeAttribute(java.lang.String name,
                                java.lang.Object value,
                                java.lang.String property)
                         throws java.io.IOException

Parameters:
    name - Attribute name to be added
    value - Attribute value to be added
    property - Name of the property or attribute (if any) of the UIComponent associated with the containing element, to which this generated attribute corresponds
```

Why does the ResponseWriter need to know the backing property? Again, it seems to work fine if I pass null or, "styleClass" when writing the class attribute.

Curious minds want to know, and my google-fu is failing on this one...

Comment: As far as I understand, these are mostly for debugging purposes, maybe for some weird `ResponseWriter` implementations. Standard ones certainly don't care, I usually just pass `null` and not bother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard Mojarra implementation does *nothing* with them. The `component` argument of `startElement()` and the `property` argument of `writeAttribute()` are plain ignored.

However, it's possible to provide a custom response writer. For some real world implementations it would make completely sense to know about the originating `UIComponent` and/or the associated `UIComponent` property inside the response writer.

Although JSF 2.0 targeted, the [`Html5ResponseWriter` of OmniFaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/renderkits/Html5RenderKit) would be a good example. The `startElement()` determines the type of the `UIComponent` by several `instanceof` checks before allowing/writing some specific HTML5 attributes.

Comment: Yes I looked at your really nice html5ResponseWriter and left a comment on your blog about it. The sooner we can upgrade to WAS 8 and JSF2.0 the better!