# Difference between 'name' and 'property' argument in ResponseWriter.writeAttribute()

Tags: jsf-2

What is the difference between `name` and `property` in [`ResponseWriter.writeAttribute(String name, Object value, String property)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ResponseWriter.html#writeAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String))? Also, what if `property` is `null`?

Comment: Javadoc is pretty clear
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/javaserverfaces/1.1_01/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ResponseWriter.html#writeAttribute(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)

Comment: Can also refer to this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810219/jsf-1-2-startelement-and-writeattribute-explanation

Comment: I have read it ... but its not clear to me. Can you please give a good example of it for more clarification?
Take this example and please explain - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnavu.html#bnavw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `name` is the HTML attribute name you'd like to write out. The `property` is the JSF tag attribute name (as indicated by a property on `UIComponent` class) associated with that HTML attribute.

Usually (and that's for a lot of attributes), those are the same. E.g. `<h:inputText value>` which ends up as `<input value>`.

```
writer.writeAttribute("value", value, "value");
```

However, for e.g. JSF attribute `styleClass` this is different, because the associated HTML attribute name `class` is a reserved keyword in Java and you can't have a property like `private String class` without facing a compilation error. JSF components therefore use `styleClass` as tag attribute name and component property. So e.g. `<h:inputText styleClass>` ends up as `<input class>`.

```
writer.writeAttribute("class", styleClass, "styleClass");
```

The `property` can be specified with `null` if there is *actually* no such attribute in the JSF tag and/or `UIComponent` class. E.g. custom HTML5 attributes via a custom component or renderer.

```
writer.writeAttribute("autofocus", "true", null);
```

So, usually only when both `UIComponent#getAttributes()` don't contain the key and `UIComponent#getValueExpression()` returns `null` and the property is unknown in JSF state.